# Vue: Having a v-model on a Select dropdown clears other input values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a form with input values.  When I have a select with a v-model on it and go to change the drop down value, the input from the previous fields clear.  I made a simple codepen to demonstrate this.  It's been a pain point for me for a while but now it's starting to interfere with customer experience so I'd like to see why this happens.

https://codepen.io/lorvenji9533/pen/VwvVBMV

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input></input>
      <select v-model="foo">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: ""
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times. If you have more information to add, [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61862250/edit)

Comment: @Phil can I close that?  It was downvoted before I had this info to add and I feel like no one is going to look at it now

Comment: It's not downvoted now and if you edit the question, it will bump back to the front page